# find a row based on serverl creiteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
id  var status warehouse
1    x    True    1
2    x    False   1  
3    y    False   1
```

I want to write a query where I give it `var` and it returns me only one row as follows.
if it has status=True it will return this row first, if not it will return any status. if none found it will return nothing.

For example
for `x` it will return `id=1`   (2 is wrong!)
for `y` it will return `id=3` 
for `z` it will return nothing.

I know I can do it in a function with 2 queries like:

```
select id into choose_id
from tab
where var=given_input and and status
limit 1;

IF choose_id IS NULL THEN
   select id into choose_id
   from tab
   where var=given_input 
   limit 1;
END IF;

continue work with choose_id
```

where `given_input` is `'x'` or `'z'` or `'y'`

is it doable in a single query without `IF` statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from tab t
where var = $var
order by (case when status = true then 1 else 2 end)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Can't you just do `ORDER BY status DESC`?

Comment: @jarlh . . . Yes, that is a simplification for true/false.  To be honest, though, I think less experienced users often find it confusing that true < false.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Actually `order by (case when status = true then 1 else 2 end)` and `ORDER BY status DESC` are not the same. `Null` values which are also possible in a boolean filed will be ordered differently in each of the option, so these are not identical solutions.